# Recovering Deleted Data onto the Same Drive

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, data-recovery

I just accidentally deleted pretty much all of my data. It is on a separate partition, and I have not touched anything except to try some undeleters.

The biggest problem is that it is terabytes of data. I do not have enough room to copy these deleted files to another partition. It seems to me that there should be a way to just rewrite the partition table without even touching the data. I really do not see how I could ever get this data back without using its original partition. But there has to be a utility out there smart enough not to overwrite the data it is recovering. Note: I think that partition had enough free space to hold the lost data twice.

Secondly different utilities seem to get different results. NTFS Undelete show basically all perfect "excellent" status,  and 2 out of thousands as "good". Recuva shows a quite a bit as unrecoverable.

Comment: what exactly is your question? the easiest way around your problem is to buy an external drive, recover the files and return it.

Comment: Not sure you want to hear as an answer its not possible to recover files on the same drive as your trying to recover files from well I suppose it's possible it's just that it will fail to recover files as they are overwriten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you always must recover to a different partition from the one you're recovering from is because the software doesn't tell the HDD where to place the recovered data.

When your utility is specificly reading from "empty" portions of the disk (which is what disk recovery utilities do) and then telling the drive to write data back to that same drive, you're just asking for trouble.

The right, and only, thing to do is to use a second drive as your recovery target.

The good news for you is that drives are cheap, and when you're done you'll have another large drive to lose things on!